# Putting included layout at top and bottom of main layout

Tags: android, android-layout, include

I am reusing a layout via the include tag.
I need on of them to be at the top and one at the bottom.
Problem is that both are coming at the top.
It is totally ignoring the layout_below and layout_alignParentBottom

This is the main XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:background="#009933">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lloAdMod"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="@dimen/ad_width"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/ad_height">
             <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="**************"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:background="#009933" android:layout_below="@id/lloAdMod">
    <TextView   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                android:id="@+id/tvwMoveMessage" android:text="" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:scrollHorizontally ="true" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:background="#F3F781" android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="marquee" 
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"/> 

    <include    layout="@layout/card_layout_horizontal"  android:id="@+id/layCardsTop"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvwMoveMessage"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:visibility="visible"/>   




    <include    layout="@layout/card_layout_horizontal"  android:id="@+id/layCardsBottom"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:visibility="visible"/>   

 </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the included one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/ivwCard2"  android:layout_width="46dip" android:layout_height="62dip"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" android:contentDescription="@string/card"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:visibility="invisible"/> 
    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/ivwCard3"  android:layout_width="46dip" android:layout_height="62dip"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivwCard2" 
                android:visibility="invisible" android:contentDescription="@string/card"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/ivwCard4"  android:layout_width="46dip" android:layout_height="62dip"
                android:src="@drawable/icon"  android:contentDescription="@string/card"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivwCard3" 
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/ivwCard1"  android:layout_width="46dip" android:layout_height="62dip"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ivwCard2" 
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"  android:contentDescription="@string/card" />
    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/ivwCard0" android:layout_width="46dip" android:layout_height="62dip"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ivwCard1" 
                android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"  android:contentDescription="@string/card" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I could create a LinearLayout at the top and bottom, put the layout_* attribute there and then do the include within that.
Is there not a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Both the includes are inside the inner RelativeLayout(android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"). If you want to place it relative to the outer RelativeLayout, please place the included layouts outside the relativeLayout2.

Comment: I need them both relative to the inner RelativeLayout. The outer one is to divide the ads from the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You have not put into *include* tag the width and height. Both the *include* tag and the root layout that is included need to have width and height. Today I struggled with *include* positioning, too, until I found that solution. (The automatic extraction by Eclipse helped me).

Answer (score 0):

place the layout outside android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
same as above! but the only solution :)